# Groovy/grails how to call controller method from view using jquery

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a Groovy/Grails project with a view that has some data rendered to it from its controller, say the controller is called MyController and the data I want to render is called ${myData}. The relevant part of my view looks like this:

```
<head>
    $('#refreshData').click(function(){
        //here I want to run the method in my controller and update the value of myData
    });
    ...
</head>    

<body>
    ...    
    <input type="text" id="inputData" />
    <button id="refreshData">Submit</button>
    ...
</body>
```

My controller has an action that receives an argument of type String (it's supposed to receive it from the input form)

```
def updateData(String input) {
    //updating input
    [myData: return_value]
}
```

I want to call the action updateData from my jquery function either by having a local js variable assigned with the return value of that function or by having a variable rendered to my view and accessing it. I tried calling

```
var newData = ${
    remoteFunction(
        controller: 'my', 
        action: 'updateData', 
        params =[string_from_form]
    )};
```

but I am getting the error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` with a message of the form

> No signature of method <> is applicable for values (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.ArrayList) values: [[controller:my...

Can somebody please tell me how to call the controller method with my parameter from that jQuery function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might have a bug in the params section of your code. Try:

```
var newData = ${remoteFunction(controller: 'my', action: 'updateData', params: '[string_from_form]')};
```

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem, but I resorted to $.post("${createLink(controller:..., action:...), param1:..., function(data)={...}}"). Seems more js like.

Answer (score 0):

You want `params:` instead of `params =`.