# Calling controller function from gsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy

I need to call a controller function from javascript on my gsp.
I have read different solutions from hundreds of places but none worked.
The problem which I found closest to mine was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552196/groovy-grails-how-to-call-controller-method-from-view-using-jquery).
But I am not repeating the same mistake as this and thus the solution didn't help.

I have a tag like this which calls the javascript function

```
<g:select name="poNumber" noSelection="['':'Select PO Number']" from="${com.rerq.PurchaseOrder.list()}" 
                    onchange="getProject(this.value)" />
```

And the javascript function looks like this

```
function getProject(poNumber){
        var projectName = document.getElementById("projectName");
        var newData = ${remoteFunction(controller: 'sow', action: 'getProject', params: ['poNumber':poNumber])};
}
```

And the function I need to call is

```
def getProject(String poNumber) {
        String projectName = Sow.find("from Sow as s where s.poNumber=?", [poNumber])
        return projectName
    }
```

The controller function might have mistakes as I am completely new to groovy and grails. But my understanding is that the control isn't reaching here so this should not be the cause of any problem.

I am getting below exception

> No signature of method: remoteFunction() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[controller:sow, action:getProject, params:[poNumber:null]]]

I tried using remoteFunction() in g:select itself but it threw another exception which said

> Attribute value quotes not closed ...

even though they were.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? If it's Grails 3, do you have the ajax-tags plugin installed? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979604/how-to-build-a-drop-down-dymic-using-ajax-in-grails-3-0/34981276#34981276

Comment: I am using 3.0.9 and installing ajax-tags removed the exception. Though I changed the approach because there were other problems. Anyways, thank you for the help. If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use remoteFunction with Grails 3 you need to add the ajax-tags plugin: org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can have your gsp recognize some Grails functions inside your js if the script is inside the gsp and anything you need for your js is created on the server side. In your case it seems you want to do an ajax call so you could have the following.

project.gsp (Consider that you already loaded jQuery)

```
<g:select name="poNumber" noSelection="['':'Select PO Number']" from="${com.impetus.rerq.PurchaseOrder.list()}" 
                    onchange="getProject(this.value)" />
```

And in the same file you have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getProject(poNumber){
    jQuery("#yourTarget").load("${createLink(action: 'getProject')}",{poNumber: poNUmber},function(response, status, xhr ){
                   if ( status == "error" ) {
                       alert("No data loaded.")
                   }
                });
    }

</script>
```

As you see a gstring in `load("${}",...` is used because it will be parsed in the server and at client side  your actual js it will parse to `load("yourcontrollerName/getProject",....`. Why not code the url directly in the js? Because by using `createLink()` it is less likely to make reference mistakes.

### **EDIT**

If you want to do this but using an external js file, you would need a way to pass the url, to the js, and use a simple load function. So something like this will be helpful

```
<g:select name="poNumber" noSelection="['':'Select PO Number']" from="${com.impetus.rerq.PurchaseOrder.list()}" 
                        onchange="getProject(this.value, \'${createLink(action:'getProject')}\')" />
```

Once on the server `onchange="getProject(this.value,\'${createLink(action:'getProject')}\')"`would be parsed to `onchange="getProject(this.value,'yourController/getProject')"`. Be wary that I might have messed up the ""s and ''s so verify your html output.
And you would need a js function that accepts the uri

```
function getProject(value, targetUri){
....
}
```

What you need to review is when is your function needed, on the server o in the client;if the functions are inside a gsp or not; And if not available, how could you pass data to them.

Comment: I do not have jquery loaded. I am trying to do it by adding this to the build file-
runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"
compile "org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.10.4"

and this to the gsp file
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>

and the following to config.groovy
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"

But the build is failing and I am not able to run the application. Am I not doing it the right way?

Comment: You could simply add it directly in the <head>  of your main layout like <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text-javascript"></script>. The src is https : //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js minus the spaces.

Comment: Also check how this is done using either resources plugin or less asset pipeline plugin. I think it is an overkill to add a full plugin just for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `grails's controller` from `javascript`. I haven't tested it but this might work.

```
<g:createLink controller="sow" action="getProject", params="['poNumber':poNumber]"/>
```

Also, if you use Google Chrome's developer's tool, you will see how your `javascript` code is displayed. Make sure it is in right syntax.

Comment: there is also   <g:include controller="something" action="doSomething" id="${some.id}" /> so in javascript it would be ${g.include(controller:'seomthing',action:'doSomething',id:'1')}